# How to tag content by users and filter the content in a view?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a content type Meeting Minutes. I'd like to tag users in the minutes. There will be a view to the list of minutes only for the logged in user.

For example:

- Meeting 1, tags Peter, Mary
- Meeting 2, tags Paul, Mary
- Meeting 3, tags Peter

When Mary logs in, the view shows:

- Meeting 1
- Meeting 2

When Peter logs in, the view shows:

- Meeting 1
- Meeting 3

Is there a user tags module for a content type and good for view-filter?

Answer (score 1):

Add `entity reference` field in `Meeting Minutes` use entity type `user` and then tag users from there with you  content of Meeting
now in views 
use `Contextual filters`
add `Contextual filters` select you user reference field like if your field name is

```
Content: user in meeting
```

then select

```
Provide default value
```

from check boxes a select list will be appear then select from them

```
User ID from logged in user
```

and done 
Now when page load content should be filtered with current user id
i think this will solve your problem